# Is there any sentiment analysis algorithm to identify sentiment of a sentence towards a certain word in the sentence?

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'll start with some examples. Think about a sentence like "Mazda CX5 is a good car.". NLTK sentiment analysis module "Vader" will give a positive polarity score on the sentence. Meanwhile a positive score will also be assigned to a sentence like "Mazda CX5 is a better car compared to Subaru Forester." However, the sentence in fact has a negative sentiment towards Subaru Forester. I wonder if there is any algorithm can actually identify such sentiment difference between the general sentiment and sentiment against a certain word in the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aspect based analysis tried to solve above problem. It categorizes data by aspect and assign sentiment to it. Lets say you have a restaurant review :

**Food was good and service was bad**

It will create 2 categories :

1. Aspect : Food Sentiment : Positive
2. Aspect : Service Sentiment : Negative

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. Here it is what I  did

1. Parts of speech tagging with spacy
2. Extract relationship. In your case it will be object(Mazda) comparative (than) object (Subaru) .
3. .label the data  set using multi labels: positive object , negative object . Each sentence will have two labels. For  example under positive write Mazda,  under negative write Subaru.
4. Train using word2vec approach.